# PHP session_id() not accepting existing session id

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I'm having trouble forcing sessions to restart in PHP. Here's the problem:

I can get my session id with `session_id()`, copy it, and add to the very top of my script:

```
session_id('the_session_id');
session_start();
```

And when I open a new browser, the session from the other browser is not carried over. What settings can I check?

Comment: "when i open a new browser" - do you mean like if you have FF and then open IE?

Comment: did you found a solution to this problem because I need same thing with my session?

Answer (score 0):

**Reason:**

If you close the browser window and open it again, then at this moment a second session is started with a different ID, if the used web application has some session based authentication system the user has to login again. At the same time the user has to logout twice!

**Solution:**

This function will use a real cookie for the session ID and updates the expiration time with every script execution. The expiration is equal to the PHP directive "gc_maxlifetime" (default) or every custom value. So, put this function in your PHP file. We will need it.

```
<?php 

// $expire = the time in seconds until a session have to expire 
function start_session($expire = 0)
{ 
    if ($expire == 0)
        $expire = ini_get("session.gc_maxlifetime"); 
    else
        ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", $expire); 

    if (empty($_COOKIE['PHPSESSID']))
    { 
        session_set_cookie_params($expire); 
        session_start(); 
    }
    else
    { 
        session_start(); 
        setcookie("PHPSESSID", session_id(), time() + $expire); 
    } 
} 

?>
```

Now, in the top of your page where you're issuing `session_id('the_session_id');` and `session_start();`, remove those lines and start session with this code below:

To start a session with an expire time given by the php configuration

```
start_session();
```

To start a session that will expire in 1 hour:

```
start_session(3600);
```

Comment: Thank you. Let me be a little more specific about what I'm doing because I think it makes a difference. I'm using a flash uploader, and when the Flash plugin executes the PHP upload script, the session breaks, and I get a 302. So I'm passing PHPSESSID as a post param with the Flash request, and on each page I have:

if(isset($_POST['PHPSESSID'])) {
session_id($_POST['PHPSESSID']);
session_start();
}

But when I dump the $_SESSION, it's always empty when the session id is assigned in that block.

It seems to work fine on most servers. Is this technique blocked by any php.ini settings?